Regex and wildcard in BQ load
I have 5000 Avro files need upload those into bq table, but need to upload from (0-0550) files
File name
—————————
00000 of 05000.avro
00001 of 05000.avro
00002 of 05000.avro
..
….
….
05000 of 05000.avro
Used below query,
Bq load —soruce_format=AVRO —replace dataset.tablname gs://bucket/fldr1/*<0-5>.Avro
So the query upload series of 0-5 but query failed
Any idea how upload 500 files using wildcard or regex?
